# Puppet for a hat

Tags: riddle

> Smallest by the banded one, the biggest, then the lead
>
> Extend to wave or crouch in anger, half-way-hunch to knead
>
> The clever use them alike the dim, though perhaps not to count
>
> The most unfortunate of folk may vary in amount

Answer (score 11):

The answer is:

> **FINGERS**

*Smallest by the banded one, the biggest, then the lead*

> In order, from the outside of the hand we have:
>
>  - The *smallest* (pinky);
>  - The *banded* one (ring);
>  - The *biggest* (middle);
>  - The *lead* (index - the one that can be used to point the way).

*Extend to wave or crouch in anger, half-way-hunch to knead*

> You stretch out (*extend*) your fingers while waving, clench your fists (as if your fingers are *crouching*) when angry and looking for a fight, and do something partway between the two when *kneading* dough.

*The clever use them alike the dim, though perhaps not to count*

> Everybody uses fingers (no matter their intelligence), and the mathematically minded may use them when learning to count.

*The most unfortunate of folk may vary in amount.*

> Some people may *unfortunately* have lost one in an accident.

As for the title:

> *Finger puppets!*